# Python 3 threads aren't running any task greater than the number of threads

Tags: python, multithreading

I'm having issues with threads not executing. I followed the docs on how to setup threads and it works great, except it hangs after finishing the first batch of tasks. Basically it mounts locally the remote server log directory, then parses the log for two particular strings. When those first 10 threads finish it hangs and never moves on to the over servers. What am I doing wrong?

```
'''
Created on Feb 10, 2012
This script exists solely to check the configs of prod servers for oom exceptions
 and restarts
'''
import shlex
import subprocess
import time
import re
import os
import logging
import logging.handlers
import queue
import threading
from threading import Lock
import getpass


#search string:
ss = "outofmemory"
password = getpass.getpass("Please type in your sea1 password to mount the drives locally: ")
user = getpass.getuser()

max_threads = 9
log_home = os.path.expanduser("~")
log_path = os.path.join(log_home, "Desktop")
log_file = 'Server Parser.log'
log_out = os.path.join(log_path, log_file)
logger = logging.getLogger("Server Parser")
tg_logger = logging.getLogger('thread')
tg_logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
tp_logger = logging.getLogger('tpwipe')
tp_logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

outFile = "Server Parser (with {} threads).log".format(max_threads)
output_path = os.path.join(log_path, outFile)
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
# create file handler which logs even debug messages
fh = logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler(log_out, mode='a', 
                                          maxBytes=2000000, 
                                          backupCount=6)
fh.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
# create console handler with a higher log level
ch = logging.StreamHandler()
ch.setLevel(logging.INFO)
# create formatter and add it to the handlers
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
fh.setFormatter(formatter)
ch.setFormatter(formatter)
# add the handlers to the logger
logger.addHandler(fh)
logger.addHandler(ch)
tp_logger.addHandler(fh)
tp_logger.addHandler(ch)
tg_logger.addHandler(ch)
tg_logger.addHandler(fh)
q = queue.Queue()
lock = Lock()
class ThreadShredder(threading.Thread):
    """threaded information aggregator"""
    def __init__(self, myqueue, search_string, l, thr, user, password):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.q = myqueue
        self.ss = search_string
        self.logger = logging.getLogger("thread".format(thr))
        self.thread_num = thr
        self.lock = l
        self.p = password
        self.u = user
    def run(self):
        '''
        will mount all the drives and start parsing, like a boss
        '''
        def wait_check(dl):
            if os.path.exists(dl+":\\"):
                self.logger.info("Mount exists, waiting til it frees to continue")
                time.sleep(20)
                wait_check(dl)
        self.lock.acquire()
        qi = self.q.get()
        drive_letter = qi[1]
        wait_check(drive_letter)
        direc = qi[0]
        host = qi[2]
        u = self.u
        p = self.p
        self.logger.debug("Thread: {} folder: {}".format(self.thread_num, direc))
        mount_cmd = r"net use {}: {} {} /USER:sea1\\{}".format(drive_letter, direc, p, u)
        args = shlex.split(mount_cmd)
        self.logger.debug("Thread: {} mount args: {}".format(self.thread_num, args))
        p = subprocess.Popen(args)
        self.lock.release()
        time.sleep(1)
        logFile = os.path.join("{}:\\".format(drive_letter), "Server-app.log")
        ex_time = []
        last_restart = None
        with open(logFile, encoding="utf-8", errors="ignore", mode="r") as data:
            for line in data:
                if line.rstrip("\n") == "System.OutOfMemoryException: Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.":
                    continue
                line_tokens = line.split()
                if len(line_tokens) >= 7:
                    if line_tokens[6] == "Service" and line_tokens[7] == "starting...":
                        last_restart = line_tokens[1]
                if self.ss in line.lower().rstrip("\n"):
                    if len(line_tokens) >= 6:
                        job = line_tokens[1]
                        if job == "Exception" or "," not in job:
                            continue
                        ex_time.append(job)
            if len(ex_time) > 0:
                self.logger.info("OOM Exception detected on {} at {}".format(host, ex_time[-1]))
                if last_restart != None:
                    self.logger.info("last restart on {} at {}".format(host, last_restart))
        time.sleep(10)
        unmount = "net use {}: /DELETE".format(drive_letter)
        unmntCom = shlex.split(unmount)
        np = subprocess.Popen(unmntCom)
        np
        self.q.task_done()

srv_log_dir = ["l$", "logs"]
srv_log = "Service-app.log"
srv_log_path = os.path.join(rmp_log_dir[0], rmp_log_dir[1], rmp_log)
odd_list = ["mycoolserver", "mycoolserver1", "mycoolserver3", "mycoolserver4"]
win_drive_letters = ["e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m",
                     "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v",
                     "w", "x", "y", "z"]
win_drive_list = []
full_log_path = []
job_list = []
srv_list = []
folder_string = r'"\\\\server\l$\logs"'
len_rzt = len(odd_list)

for i in range(max_threads):
    j = i + 1
    t = ThreadShredder(q, ss.lower(), lock, j, user, password)
    t.setDaemon(True)
    t.start()

def find_drives():
    '''
    Creates contiguous block of ten drive letters that aren't being used
    '''
    drive_block = set()
    for i in range(10):
        if not os.path.exists(win_drive_letters[i]+":\\") and win_drive_letters[i] not in drive_block:
            drive_block.add(win_drive_letters[i])
            logger.debug("{} {}".format(i, drive_block))
        elif not os.path.exists(win_drive_letters[i+1]+":\\") and win_drive_letters[i+1] not in drive_block:
            drive_block.add(win_drive_letters[i+1])
            logger.debug("{} {}".format(i, drive_block))
        elif not os.path.exists(win_drive_letters[i+2]+":\\") and win_drive_letters[i+2] not in drive_block:
            drive_block.add(win_drive_letters[i+2])
            logger.debug("{} {}".format(i, drive_block))
    return sorted(drive_block)
db = find_drives()
for elem in db: 
    win_drive_list.append(elem)
    logger.debug("available drive letters: {}".format(elem))
#12 is the number of copy move servers we have
for i in range(12 + len_rzt):
    z = i - 12
    j = i + 1
    x = i
    if i > 9 and i < 20:
        x = i - 10
    elif i > 19 and i < 30:
        x = i - 20
    elif i > 29 and i < 40:
        x = i - 30
    if i < 9: 
        srv_list.append("server0{}".format(j))
    else:
        srv_list.append("server{}".format(j))
    if i == 9:
        logger.debug("{} ".format(srv_list[i], win_drive_list[x]))
    if i < 12:
        folder = re.sub('server', srv_list[i], folder_string)
        job_list.append(([folder, win_drive_list[x], rmp_list[i]]))
    else:
        folder = re.sub('server', odd_list[z], folder_string)
        job_list.append(([folder, win_drive_list[x], odd_list[z]]))
    logger.info(job_list[i])

for i, job in enumerate(job_list):
    q.put(job)
q.join()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `.run()` method finishes after processing a single item from the queue. Change it to:

```
while True:
    job = q.get()
    # ...
```

There are many other problems in your code.

Comment: I added that line, and now it hangs without any of the threads launching.

Comment: @user352472: `# ...` denotes all the statements in the `.run()` method.

Comment: Hot damn, that worked. Thanks oh so very much! Now I've got other issues, but I'll try and suss them out.